# Calling unmanaged methods from managed code

Tags: c#, c++, mono, cil, reflection.emit

Let's assume I have an unmanaged class *Test*:

```
class Test
{
public:
    int SomeMethod(int a, bool b);
};
```

To create a new instance of Test, I'd:

```
Test *test = new Test();
```

My goal is to embed Mono so that managed code could call unmanaged methods (like `Test::SomeMethod`) in a specific object. I represent that object by passing a pointer of that object to the managed method, like that:

```
void *args[1];
args[0] = &test;

mono_runtime_invoke(init, NULL, args, NULL);
```

Here is how the managed method that is being invoked looks like:

```
public static void Init(IntPtr test)
{

}
```

From here, how can I call `Test.SomeMethod`?

I thought about using emitting the `CALLI` instruction, using `System.Reflection.Emit`, but how can I refer to the object that the pointer `test` (the first parameter of `Init`) is referring to?

I do *not* want to use `DllImport`.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use `[DllImport]`?

Comment: Because it means that I'd have to export some unmanaged methods that I can't export.

Comment: So write a function that you *can* export.  Have it call the function that you can't export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in [CXXI](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html). It creates a managed assembly based on your C++ headers and allows you to work with C++ objects as if they were normal managed objects.

As far as I understand it, it's not finished yet and works only with C++ code compiled by GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done (Or at least shouldn't be done).

You're trying to directly mix two completely different execution environments - the reason why `DLLImport` exists is to allow the compiler to solve this problem.

In .NET, you can create mixed-mode applications (C++/CLI) which allow managed code and unmanaged code to co-exist in the same binary (and call each other), but since you're talking about mono, I'm assuming that option is out.

Managed environments like .NET have strict type rules, garbage collection and other features that simply don't work with unmanaged code and data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an internal call, if you don't want to use DllImport.
See https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/samples/embed/teste.c the mono_add_internal_call() invocation and the C# code in the test.cs file.
This works mostly like DllImport, except there is no marshalling done for you (a string object in C# code will appear as a MonoString* in the C code, not as a char*, for example).

In any case, note that both the function you could access with DllImport and the function pointer registered with mono_add_internal_call() must be C functions, not C++ member methods.